# Sync text and audio

Tags: objective-c, iphone

How can i Sync text with the audio i have a given text and audio i just want a hint how can i sync them

Answer (score 1):

you have to write a file with timecodes, then you can show the text at the given time.

Like [SubRip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip)

```
1
00:00:20,000 --> 00:00:24,400
Altocumulus clouds occur between six thousand

2 
00:00:24,600 --> 00:00:27,800 
and twenty thousand feet above ground level.
```

cheers Simon